# NAudio mix 2 two audio togeter with WaveMixerStream32() -->how to let second audio start later

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

i' trying to get a simple mix with audio delay of two audio files to get working.

I have two audios. Each has a length of 30 seconds. If a mix them them together with WaveMixerStream32 they are layed on top of each other (length of mixed wave would be 30 seconds)

```
 var mixer = new WaveMixerStream32 { AutoStop = true};

 var readerAudio1 = new WaveFileReader("pathtoAudio1");
 var readerAudio2 = new WaveFileReader("pathtoAudio2");

 mixer.AddInputStream(new WaveChannel32(readerAudio1));
 mixer.AddInputStream(new WaveChannel32(readerAudio2));
 WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("mycomposed.wav", new Wave32To16Stream(mixer));
```

Is it possible to start audio 2 with an delay of 10 seconds-->this means the result would have a length of 40 seconds at the end.

I tryed to use

```
 var offset = new OffsetSampleProvider(readerAudio2);
 offset.DelayBy = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

but dont't know how to get the delay working with the mixer.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thank you for any help. Jana

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MixingSampleProvider` for mixing, then you can use it in conjunction with `OffsetSampleProvider`